# MySQL - Select query to return all cols but only 1 of each combination of 2 identifying columns

Tags: mysql, select

I need to write a mysql query that returns all columns, but only 1 of each set of identifying columns.
i.e.

I have a table with a primary key on 3 fields (firstName, lastName, effDate). I can have x amount of rows with the same firstName and lastName but all have different effDates. I've included an example set of data below. I need to write a query that returns the most recent firstName + lastName combination. Is this possible?
something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(firstName, lastName), * FROM table ORDER BY effData DESC;
```

example data:

**FirstName  lastName   effDate**

Will       Johnson    2021-02-02

Will       Johnson    2021-03-02

Will       Johnson    2021-04-02

Sam        Red        2021-02-23

Sam        Red        2021-04-28

example return:

**FirstName  lastName   effDate**

Will         Johnson    2021-04-02

Sam          Red        2021-04-28

Comment: Which effDate do you want to show?  Consider `MIN`, `MAX`, `ANY_VALUES`, `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

To get from your example data to the desired result, all you need to do is group by `firstName, lastName` and take the `max` `effDate`:

```
select firstName
      ,lastName
      ,max(effDate) effDate
from   table
group by firstName
        ,lastName
```

If you want to grab more information from the rows that contain the most recent `effDate` you can use an analytic function to provide an ordered column that can be used for filtering:

```
select firstName
      ,lastName
      ,effDate
from  (
select firstName
      ,lastName
      ,effDate
      ,row_number() over (partition by firstName, lastName order by effDate desc) rn
from   table
      ) sq
where rn = 1
```

(assuming `effDate` can't be null)